# Camel validate against file from classpath

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I want to validate xml against schema - using SpringBoot 2 and camel 3.

On localhost this works:

```
.to("validator:file:src/main/resources/D.xsd")
```

But when uploaded to server on tomcat machine with context for example `D` - i get an error:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/main/resources/D.xsd (No such file or directory)
```

I think that i need to change the path to use classpath - but i am not sure how to make it work ?

**What i tried:**

```
.to("validator:file:classpath:/src/main/resources/D.xsd")
```

```
.to("validator:file:resource:classpath:src/main/resources/D.xsd")
```

```
.to("validator:file:resource:classpath:/src/main/resources/D.xsd")
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In one of my applications (but with SpringBoot 1.5 and Camel 2.x) this works fine

```
.to("validator:classpath:folder/filename.xsd")
```

to validate against `filename.xsd` that is located in `src/main/resources/folder`

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it with:

```
.to("validator:D.xsd")
```

Comment: Nice. Seems like "classpath:" is the default, so it is the same as my answer :-)